# MVC3 Razor jQuery autocomplete passes old value to Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

I am trying to implement auto complete however I'm finding that it is not passing the partial string, I'm using MVC3, the razor view engine and jquery to put it all together.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">  </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript">   </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (request) {
    alert("test:" + $("#searchTerm").val());
    $("#searchTerm").autocomplete({
        source: "/Home/GetAccounts/" + $("#searchTerm").val(),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: request.term,
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            window.location.href = 'Home/GetAccounts/' + ui.item.value;
        }
    });
});

</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{               
 <form method="post" action="">
 <input id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" type="text" />
     <input type="submit" value="Go" />
 </form>

}
```

And Below is the Controller

```
    public ActionResult GetAccounts(string id)
    {
        var accounts = NavRepository.GetAccountsBasedOnString(id);
        var accountStrings = new string[accounts.Count];
        var count = 0;

        foreach (var account in accounts)
        {
            accountStrings[count] = account.AccountID;
            count++;
        }

        return Json(accountStrings, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I did hunt around a few places (such as http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp ) including here but I just can't seem to crack this one.

Additional Here is how I write my routes.

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

And as noted in the comments if i set value="test" for searchTerm it only sends this string

Comment: what's actually going wrong?  is it hitting GetAccounts without a parameter?

Comment: Yep, hits there but id is null, and if i set a default value it is the default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you set the source of your autocomplete it takes the value of the textfield at the moment this is done (i.e. at DOM load) => the value is empty at this stage. The document.ready event handler doesn't take a request object.

You could pass a function to the `source` property when wiring your autocomplete:

```
$(function() {
    $('#searchTerm').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAccounts", "Home")',
                data: { id: request.term },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("GetAccounts", "Home")' + ui.item.value;
                }
          });
    });
});
```

Comment: This solved the issue after adding a brace, however it does not display when I get a chance I will retest this to make sure it is not something else affecting this.